# What is that distance on the chat?

Tags: league-of-legends

After patch 4.13, I believe, I see a "distance" on the chat with yellow colored letters now and then and I don't know if I'm causing this or what it is. It shows a number like "456.90349238" and that's all. What is that and how does it appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the [Quinn Vault Glitch](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=4736399). Every time she uses her E (Vault) it does that irritating distance message in the chat. There is no way to fix it right now so we'll just have to wait for Riot to patch it.